# Add to Collection if not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an `embedded document` in my collection name as `likes`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a31e18fa0299542ab8dd80"),
    "created" : ISODate("2016-08-04T10:51:04.971Z"),
    "likes" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("1"),
            "date" : 123
        }, 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("2"),
            "date" : 456
        }
    ],
    "comments" : [],
    "tag" : []
}
```

A `User` can **like** only one time. So there must be only one entry per `User`.

**The problem is:** It looks for `date` too in the object list, though I just want to search the `user` and add `current date` if entry not found. Because `date` differs every time and I get duplicated entries for same `user`.

Here is my `mongoose` query:

```
var likeObj = {
    "user": "1",        //user id
    "date": Utils.getUnixTimeStamp()    //date
};

post.update({_id: postId}, {$addToSet: {"likes": likeObj}} ,function(err,doc){
    //success
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the user to the query:

```js
 post.update({_id: postId, 
                 likes: {$not: {$elemMatch: {user: likeObj.user}}}},
                         {$addToSet: {"likes": likeObj}} ,function(err,doc){
       
    });
```